# Proving that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)!!}=\sqrt{e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proving that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)!!}=\sqrt{e}$$
Firstly, I tried to check the value with the exponential function at $x=.5$ but I found its terms not equal to the series terms.

Comment: Could you also prove that $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)!!}=\sqrt e~\int_0^1e^{-x^2/2}~dx\quad?~$ :-)

Answer (score 22):

Note that $$(2n)!! = 2\cdot4\cdot 6 \cdots 2n = 2^n n!$$
so your series is just 
$$\sum_n \frac{(1/2)^n}{n!} = e^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 10):

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

Plug $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$, then $\dfrac{x^n}{n!} = \dfrac{1}{2^n n!} = \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots 2n} = \dfrac{1}{(2n)!!}$